# Visual Studio detecting Operater Overloading While g++ doesn't

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, g++

I have a house class. I initialize a new house element with `house house;` then I pass data into it and then I cout it:

```
cout << house;
```

Couting house works just fine in Visual Studio, but for some reason, I receive this error when I try to compile with g++:

```
error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
```

Even though I very clearly have this in one of my header files:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, house);
```

Any feedback you can give would be greatly appreciated, as I can see no reason for g++ not being able to see my operator overloading function.

Edit: Here's my operator overloading function:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const house& house)
{
    //unsigned short i = house->getSqrFt();
    out << "Address: " << house.getAddress() << std::endl
        << "Square Feet: " << house.getSqrFt() << std::endl
        << "Bedrooms: " << +house.getBedrooms() << std::endl
        << "Bathrooms: " << house.getBathrooms() << std::endl
        << "Description: " << house.getDescription() << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

And here's my class:

```
#ifndef HOUSE
#define HOUSE
class house
{
public:
    house();
    house(const char [], const char [], const short& sqrFt, const float& rating, const float& bathrooms);
    house(house & obj);
    house(house *& obj);
    ~house();
    char * getAddress() const;
    unsigned short getSqrFt() const;
    unsigned char getBedrooms() const;
    float getBathrooms() const;
    char * getDescription() const;
    void setAddress(const char address[]);
    void setSqrFt(const unsigned short& sqrFt);
    void setBedrooms(const unsigned char& bedrooms);
    void setBathrooms(const float& bathrooms);
    void setDescription(const char description[]);
    void setEqual(house &, house*);
private:
    char * address;
    unsigned short sqrFt;
    unsigned char bedrooms;
    float bathrooms;
    char * description;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but having a type (class name) and a variable with the exact same name is kind of confusing. Also, you should really use a constant reference for the type in the overloaded output operator function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg When I use a constant reference for the type in the overloaded output operator function, I receive this error: `Error: a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function`.

Comment: That sounds... weird. `friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const house&);` should work just fine and is the traditional way of declaring that function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh, I thought you meant to declare the `const` after the function before the semicolon. What you recommended worked fine in Visual Studio, but it didn't fix anything in g++.

Comment: are you sure your function declares `std::ostream& out`, and not `std::ostream&& out` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Declaring: `friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream out, house);` fixed nothing and declaring: `friend std::ostream operator<< (std::ostream& out, house);` actually stopped my code from compiling in Visual Studio.

Comment: @LarryK can you post a little more code? like the class itself, the definition  of `operator<<` etc..

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @LarryK you seem to be attempting to copy an object of type `ostream`, use references only

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki What does "use references only" mean?

Comment: @LarryK well, when either declaring a parameter of type `ostream`, or declaring a return type of any function, use `ostream&`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Do you want me to post the house class, or do you want me to post the queue class which my operator overloading function is in?

Comment: which line triggers the error? what is the full text of the error message? clearly, somewhere you are trying to copy an object of `ostream`, which is not necessarily in `operator<<`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Here's the full text of the error message: `main.cpp:36:52: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
   cout << "\nNext house to be revisited: " << endl << endl << house << endl;` I really don't see how that helps.

Comment: Your declaration `friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, house);` doesn't match your definition `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const house& house)`. The declaration should have `house` as `const &` too.